# Toggle between classes on click jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the class smallimage - when I click on smallimage I want to remove the class smallimage and add a class called bigimage.

With the code below when I click on the div it removes smallimage and adds bigimage, but when I click again it doesn't remove bigimage and add back smallimage. I want to toggle between the class smallimage and bigimage on click.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
  $('.smallimage').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bigimage');
    $(this).removeClass('smallimage');
  });

  $('.bigimage').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('smallimage');
    $(this).removeClass('bigimage');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, [**This Is The Only Correct Answer I See Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524433/toggle-between-classes-on-click-jquery#23524555)

Comment: Uh, you're not quite correct @SpYk3HH because that answer added classes that the OP did not specify and would require a change in his markup.

Comment: @JayBlanchard no it didn't, he just used a different case. easy to fix, in fact, i'll fix it. you're answer has already had a million edits and you're still doing it wrong.

Comment: Actually he change the class names.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Actually you're still just mad your answer isn't as correct. Stop arguing with people and move on. And I never said I had a problem with you. You are showing you have a problem here. Just move on.

Comment: Hahahahaha @SpYk3HH - it is just as correct as anyone's :) And thank you for editing the one you deemed most correct. Want to edit mine to screw it up?

Comment: I cannot go to chat from my current machine. C'est la vie.

Comment: @JayBlanchard seriously kid, move along. you're tying up valuable resources in comments just to prove a point you were wrong on. Get over it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following.

```
$(document).on('click','.smallimage, .bigimage', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('smallimage bigimage');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FHAg/1/)

Comment: Actually he adds classes to the equation that the OP did not specify.

Comment: Although it is correct (img shoud be image), I feel like this method had a little extra overhead

Comment: @LoganMurphy woops. Someone edited it for me :) I'll update the fiddle from `img` to `image`

Answer (score 0):

You need **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.smallimage',function() {
    $(this).addClass('bigimage');
    $(this).removeClass('smallimage');
});
$(document).on('click','.bigimage',function() {
    $(this).addClass('smallimage');
    $(this).removeClass('bigimage');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass`:

```
$('.smallimage').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('smallimage bigimage');
});
```

Assuming it starts out with a `smallimage` class name.

Here's a small, very similar demo: http://jsbin.com/wiyub/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Toggling the class is not OPs problem!

Comment: This also solves his problem though. He doesn't need to use event delegation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using toggleClass() - https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$('div.smallimage').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('smallimage bigimage');
});
```

here is a fiddle that demonstrates - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5j8aJ/2/ Use your browser's DOM inspector to see the changes.

EDIT: made an update to fit the OP's question more readily.

Comment: From OP post `I have a div with the class smallimage`

Comment: Yes? You do know that if it has the class it will be removed or added depending on its current state, right?

Comment: I meant to tell you that you should update the jquery selector to `$('div')` instead of `$('img')`. That may solve the OP's problem but its not the best way to follow. Because you do not want to attach event listeners on all the divs. Right ?

Comment: `img` should be `div.smallimage`

Comment: No @LoganMurphy, because .smallImage will not be there on the second click.

Comment: Ah, good point @blunderboy. But since he has not posted any markup we cannot be sure of his image containers - that is why I avoided it.

Comment: But the element does not lose its click event when you click it. at the moment you add the click event to all image tags inside of div tags when it is only intend for elements that currently have the class smallimage

Comment: True @LoganMurphy, but this can be confusing for new users. "How can I click on something that no longer exists?" is a question that I have answered more than a few times.

Comment: Derp - I see the interpretation that I missed as far as the div is concerned. Updating...EDIT: here is the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5j8aJ/1/

Comment: Because you selected it. Then added a click event to what you selected. The selected elements will have the click event. Period.

Comment: Sorry to have offended @LoganMurphy - and I have explained further when the time comes. I try to eliminate as much confusion as possible and users are often confused with things like this.

Comment: $('div img')  How can you make these assumptions from the OPs question?   You do not have the detail to determine if he is wrapping the img in a div.  There could be other images that he does not want this behavior that are also wrapped in div(s). I like the thought but I don't agree with your assumptions.

Comment: I made a change @JohnHartsock based on the commentary I received here and a re-reading of the OP.

Comment: eh Just go to [Dani's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524433/toggle-between-classes-on-click-jquery#23524555). It's actually correct, and simple.

Comment: Neat! I have ignited a firestorm! :)

Answer (score -1):

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/mamew/1/edit

Have a common id for the image tag:

```
<div class="smallimage" id="imageId">
  <img src=""/>
  </div>
```

Then use the following code

```
$('#imageId').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('smallimage')) {
      $(this).removeClass('smallimage').addClass('bigimage');
  }
  else {
      $(this).removeClass("bigimage").addClass('smallimage');
  }
});
```